# Waypoints animation not working on scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

Trying to create animate on scroll using Jquery waypoints. No errors in the console but effect does not happen when scrolling. If I open the developer console and then close it the effect then triggers. This is odd because this is code I am re-using from another website I made and it works fine on that website.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.js--wp-1').waypoint(function(direction) {
   $('.js--wp-1').addClass('animated fadeIn');
}, {
   offset: '50%'
});

});
```

Included script in HTML

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/
jquery.min.js"> 
</script>


<script src="Vendor/JS/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="Resources/JS/script.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
.js--wp-1 {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
}

.js--wp-1.animated {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it is now resolved. I had height set to 100% on the body, HTML on my CSS file. If anybody else finds they waypoints are not working and the code is correct it could be this.